# Headphone jack only plays background sound - MacBook Air 2011 with KDE

Tags: sound, macbook, headphones

I'm pretty new at using linux and have Kubuntu installed on my MacBook Air (2011).
Since a few weeks I have a problem with my headphone jack.
When playing videos or music the headphones give distorted sound. Background music/sound seems to play normally, but vocals are strongly reduced and barely audible.
Audio from built-in stereo behaves normally.

I have tried several things already, but can't find the cause or a solution.
I have tried:

- pulseaudio -k
- sudoedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf and inserting the line: default-fragment-size-msec = 5
- sudo Kate /etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf and adding the line: options snd-hda-intel model=generic
- Checking audio settings

Does anyone have something I could try?

Thanks!

Comment: This is quite commonly a sign of [bad hardware](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/42623/) - do other headphones on the same machine have the same problem ? Did (does) it work correctly in MacOS ?

Comment: It is a very recent problem. It worked fine when I had MacOS installed and worked fine after I switched to Kubuntu as well. Don't know the reason it started going bad. I've tested with three different pairs of headphones and there is no difference. 
I've now figured out that I can increase the vocal volume to normal with pavucontrol. However, the sound is still pretty hollow and a bit echoing. Additionally, I now need to keep changing the volume with pavucontrol everytime I close the application and open it again.

Comment: I'd suggest to try booting from a Kubuntu live USB (e.g. the one you used for installation) to rule out a potential hardware problem.